# upload files with 2 seperate input fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

there is  form the user enters the full name, age, profile pic, a document and submit. I managed to get the form working with one file upload but i cant find a proper way to upload files from 2 different inputs.

Below is my form

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name"/>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Age</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age"/>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Profile pic</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile1"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Document</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile2"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="upload" value="UPLOAD"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if ($this->input->post('upload'))
        {

            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|pdf';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000;
            $config['max_width']            = 3000;
            $config['max_height']           = 3000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
            {


                $this->session->set_flashdata('status','<div class="alert alert-danger alert-style-square">
                                            <p style="text-align:center">There was an error. Try again. '.$this->upload->display_errors().'</p>
                                        </div>');

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $values = array('full_name'=>$this->input->post('full_name'),
                        'age'=>$this->input->post('age'),
                        'profile_image'=>$this->upload->data('file_name'),
                        //'document'=>$this->upload->data('file_name'),
                        'uploaded_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));



                var_dump($values);

            }

    }
```

Your help and guides will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing

```
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
```

to

```
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1') AND !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile2'))
```

Doing this will require the user to upload both images.  If only one image is required you could try changing the **AND** to an **OR**.

Comment: Thanks... But how do i get the file name separately?

Comment: It seems like you should be using `'profile_image'=>$this->upload->data('userfile1'),` and `'document'=>$this->upload->data('userfile2'),`